# Unit testing class without using @InjectMocks

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I am trying to add unit tests for an class and I need to mock (and inject) a dependency into a class without making changes to the class under test(as that will cause lots of changes in other parts of the application which we want to avoid).

I have created the class manually (without using `@InjectMocks`) as I need to mock `AppConfig` in the test.

I am getting a null pointer exception on the line where the system expects the dependency to be injected.

What am I missing and what could I do to fix this issue?

**PageModelBuilder.java:**

```
public class PageModelBuilder {
    private final String baseUrl = AppConfig.findString("baseUrl");
    @Inject
    private StringTranslator stringTranslator;
    public PageModel buildFrom(final @NonNull ProductData productData) {
        PageModel.PageModelBuilder builder = new PageModel.PageModelBuilder();
        productData.getProductTitle().ifPresent(productTitle -> {
            builder .pageDescription(String.format(stringTranslator.getStringById("page_description_format"),
                            productTitle.getDisplayString())); //<= stringTranslator is null here
        });
        productData.getProductLink()
                .ifPresent(productLink -> builder.canonicalURL(baseUrl + productLink));
        return builder.build();
    }
}
```

**PageModelBuilderTest.java:**

```
     @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.Silent.class)
    public class PageModelBuilderTest {
        @Mock
        private StringTranslator stringTranslator;
        private PageModelBuilder pageModelBuilder;
        @Before
        public void setup() {
            if (!AppConfig.isInitialized()) {
                AppConfig.initialize("WebApp", null, new String[] {
                        "--root=.", "--domain=test"});
            }
        }
        @After
        public void after() {
            if (AppConfig.isInitialized()) {
                AppConfig.destroy();
            }
        }
        @Test
        public void givenProductDataWithProductLink_whenBuildPageModel_thenPageModelHasCanonicalURL() {
            AppConfig.insertString("baseUrl", "https://www.google.com");
when(stringTranslator.getStringById("page_description_format")).thenReturn("sample description");
            pageModelBuilder = new PageModelBuilder();
            ProductData productData = ProductTestData.getProductDataBuilder()
                    .title("TestMed")
                    .productLink("/PRODUCT-DESCRIPTION/dp/asin")
                    .build();
            PageModel pageModel = pageModelBuilder.buildFrom(productData);
            assertEquals("https://www.google.com/PRODUCT-DESCRIPTION/dp/asin", pageModel.getCanonicalURL());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which class are you expecting to be injected and which line is causing the null pointer exception?

Comment: `@InjectMock` annotation will only inject fields which are annotated with `@Mock` in test. Rest all other dependencies needs to provided by author or else they would be null. Since you created a mock but did not inject it, you are getting a null pointer. You can try adding `@InjectMocks` annotation on PageModelBuilder field and just call `pageModelBuilder.buildFrom(productData)` in your test.

Comment: @NiranjanGhule, I cannot use @InjectMocks(and have to create instance manually) as I have AppConfig instance that I need to set up.

Comment: @hooknc, I am expecting StringTranslator instance to be injected. The line stringTranslator.getStringById in PageModelBuilder throwing a NPE.

Comment: @AjitGoel I cas see 2 options: 1. Refactor your class to pass `StringTranslator` via constructor. 2. If this is not acceptable in your setting, you have to resort to reflection to set the field. `ReflectionTestUtils.setField` from spring test can be used (or regular reflection methods)

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use `@InjectMocks` and you cannot change your class to make it more testable, then you are only left with Reflection:

1. Find the field
2. Make it accessible
3. Assign your mock to the field

If you are already using Spring, then there's [`ReflectionUtils#setField`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/ReflectionUtils.html#setField(java.lang.reflect.Field,java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object)) which might come in handy.